# IntelliJ IDEA not running basic JavaScript hello world

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, ide, execution

I've created a brand new project in IDEA:

***File-> New -> Project -> Static Web -> HTML5 Boilerplate*.**

If I create a .js hello world, it won't let me run it, and "**Run**" menu only allows me to "**Edit Configurations**".

I checked JS Plugin and everything seems to be OK and activated, any hint?

**UPDATE**: Screenshot proving that is actually possible to execute JS code on IDEA Console:

[image]

Comment: I would guess that the [HTML5 Boilerplate](https://html5boilerplate.com/) template is meant to be run as a web server. You would create a Run Configuration to serve files in a certain directory, then visit the served `index.html` in your browser, and your browser would run your `.js` file if the HTML page includes it using a `<script>` element. If you only want to run raw JavaScript in your project, without it being on a page, you probably don't want a “Static Web” project.

Comment: I created this HTML5 Boilerplate template in another computer a couple of weeks ago and it let me execute .js like a charm in the console, just Ctrl+Shift+F10. I just want to execute JS in the console, do you recommend me any other project type?(In other words, I'd like to get a quick way of executing JS to test snippets, little functions and so on, is there any project type that fits better for this in IDEA?)

Answer (score 0):

Just as it's mentioned in the @Rory O'Kane comment, **HTML5 Boilerplate** is a web application supposed to be run in browser. To run it in IDEA, right-click the `index.html` in project root directory and choose **Run 'Index.html'** or **Debug 'index.html'** - application will be started on the built-in webserver

Comment: Sorry but I am not asking about how to execute the html, but just JavaScript. I know it's supposed to run in browser, but IDEA has a way to execute it on an embedded console.

Comment: IDEA can't execute js itself; it can be run either in browser or with Node.js. If you like to run your .js with Node.js, right-click the `.js` file and choose **Run**. But don't be surprised when you see ReferenceError exceptions on `window` object, for example:)

Comment: IDEA actually can execute js itself, and I can prove it with a screenshot from another PC I've got doing it. The thing is that it has to be a plugin in the other PC that does it, and this one is lacking it.

Comment: please provide this screenshot:) Haven't ever heard that IDEA can be used as javascript interpreter, even with a plugin:)

Comment: There you go with the screenshot proving that IDEA can be used as interpreter, even with a plugin :)

Comment: screenshot shows that IDEA can run your javascript with node.js interpreter via **Node.js** run configuration. But you need installing **NodeJS** plugin to get node.js support enabled. And no, it's not IDEA that interprets javascruipt, it's node.js:)